# WCF Error: ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: web-services, wcf, wsdl

I'm new to WCF and have been wrecking my brain over this one.... I am sure I am missing something. I have searched through a thousand-and-one forums but no luck with any of the suggestions to date.

The error is as follows:

*The message with Action 'http://somedomain/someinterface/someservice' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).*

The test client app works when connecting to the sample service (no documentation other than the WSDL), but get the error when I connect the same test client app to my own service that I built from the example.

I compared the WSDL definitions and other than the domain it is exactly the same. From the logs I now noticed the following. The error above is first logged, but then a second (inner exception?) is also logged, with the same error, but with the Action URL showing 'http://somedomain/someinterface/somehiddenservice'.

I need some pointers (not necessary the solution):

1. what do I need to look at here to find the issue?
2. should this "somehiddenservice" not be showing up on the WSDL?

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction will be fantastic.

Here's the config section for my webservice:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeInterface" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <basicHttpsBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_ISomeInterface"/>
        </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyNS.SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="MyNS.Service1Behavior">
            <endpoint address="http://somedomain/SomeService.svc"  binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="MyNS.ISomeInterface" />
            <endpoint address="https://somedomain/SomeService.svc"  binding="basicHttpsBinding"  contract="MyNS.ISomeInterface" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyNS.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I will send through the client config when I get home later, but in the mean time can the order of the schemaLocation nodes make a difference?

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://somedomain/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://somedomain/someservice.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://somedomain/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://somedomain/someservice.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://somedomain/someservice.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

How do you manipulate the order of xsd1, xsd0, etc?

Comment: Post your service and client config files (specifically the `<system.serviceModel>` section.  There could be a number of reasons why this error is occurring, and with the currently provided information it's difficult to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Where is your client config?   We need to see both to see where the mismatch is at.